# IE and chrome doesn't execute js code before sending an XMLHTTPRequest until it receives the response of that request

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I am building a web app using asp.net-MVC and I found some strange behavior using XmlHttpRequest to send request to server. For example, if I run the follwing js code：

```
alert("send request!");
var xhr = new new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", requestURL, false);
xhr.onreadystatechange = ResponseHandler;
xhr.send(some message);
```

If it takes a long time for the server to handle the request or if I manually set a breakpoint in the action function, I will not see the alert dialog until the server finishes processing the request. It only doesn't happen in Firefox but in IE,Safari,Opera and Chrome . This is really weird and I was wondering what is the cause of the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You're passing `false` as the third parameter to the `.open()` function, which means that you want a **synchronous** call.

Comment: thanks, but why doesn't this problem happen in firefox?

Comment: Different browsers implement `alert()` differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix it by changing the third line to:

```
xhr.open("get", requestURL, true);
```